# SetDelayed using local variables

Tags: evaluation, variable-definitions, hold

I'm trying to define `MakeBoxes` for a bunch of functions all at once, but wish to do so within a loop as in the following example:

```
{
  {a[1], "Foo"},
  {a[2], "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Goo\), \(``\)]\)"},
  {b[1], "\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(Hoo\), \(``\), \(``\)]\)"}
};
Do[
 Block[{class, number, template},
  class = Head[tmp[[1]]];
  number = First[tmp[[1]]];
  template = tmp[[2]];

  MakeBoxes[class[number], TraditionalForm] = StringTemplate[template] @@ {};
  MakeBoxes[class[number, {args__}], TraditionalForm] := StringTemplate[template] @@ {args};
  ],
 {tmp, %}
 ]
```

The problem is that the use of `SetDelayed` both `class[number, {args__}]` on the left and `template` 
on the right unevaluated, which makes subsequent calls to `TraditionalForm[a[2, {i}]` not work.

I have tried adding some combinations of `Evaluate` here and there, but so far nothing I have tried has worked.

Is it possible to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
  {a[1], "Foo"},
  {a[2], "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Goo\), \(``\)]\)"},
  {b[1], "\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(Hoo\), \(``\), \(``\)]\)"}
};
Do[
 Block[{class, number, template},
  class = Head[tmp[[1]]];
  number = First[tmp[[1]]];
  template = tmp[[2]];
  With[{class = class, number=number, template = template},
    MakeBoxes[class[number], TraditionalForm] = StringTemplate[template] @@ {};
    MakeBoxes[class[number, {args__}], TraditionalForm] := StringTemplate[template] @@ {args};
  ]
  ],
 {tmp, %}
 ]
```